# How to solve 413 : Request Entity too large error React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, body-parser

I've been struggling to find a solution for this.

I am using React as frontend and NodeJs in backend.

In backend I've added express body parser in app.js that handles max 50 mbs of file. Here's the code for it:

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: false, parameterLimit: 50000 }))
```

And from frontend, on which I use React, I am passing as file as form data for uploading videos / images in React-Quill Editor (yes for larger px images I get the same error "413 , Request Entity too large"), here's the part:

AddLesson.js:

```
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import Quill from 'quill';
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module-react';

export default function AddLesson() {

  const [course, setCourse] = useState({})
  const [contentType, setContentType] = useState('text')
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(undefined)
  const [content, setContent] = useState('')
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState('')
  const [videoPreview, setVideoPreview] = useState(undefined)
  const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false)


  const addLesson = async () => {
    setIsUploading(true);
  
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('name', title);
      formData.append('content_type', contentType);
      formData.append('content', content);
      formData.append("imageFile", imageFile);
     
      if (contentType === 'video' && video) {
        formData.append('content', video); 
      }
      formData.append('course_id', course_id);
      const response = await axios.post(url() + 'api/admin/lessons', formData);
      if (response?.status === 200) {
        setSuccess('Lesson successfully added.');
        window.setTimeout(() => {
          history.push(`/course/${course_id}/lessons`);
        }, 1000);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error?.response?.data?.msg);
      setError(error?.response?.data?.msg);
      if (title === "" || !title) {
        setError('Please provide Title');
      } else {
        setError('something went wrong');
      }
    }
    setIsUploading(false);
  };
}

  const handleSelectVideo = async(e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    console.log('files : ' , file) //yes this prints the file after i upload any video.
    if (!file) return;
    setVideo(file);
    let src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    setVideoPreview(src);
  }


  const openFileSelect = () => {
    const fileSelect = document.getElementById("upload-video");
    fileSelect.click()
  }

  const clearVideo = () => {
    setVideo(undefined)
    setVideoPreview(undefined)
  }

return (
      <div className="col-xl-5 col-lg-8 col-sm-12 mb-3">
                <h6 className="edit-box-label ml-2 mb-2">Lesson Content</h6>
                <div
                  className={`file-dragger video ${videoPreview ? 'preview' : ''}`}
                  onClick={openFileSelect}
                >
                  {videoPreview ? (
                    <video width="100%" controls style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}>
                      <source src={videoPreview} />
                    </video>
                  ) : (
                    <h6>Upload Video</h6>
                  )}
                </div>
                <input
                  id="upload-video"
                  type="file"
                  accept="video/*"
                  autoComplete="off"
                  tabIndex={-1}
                  style={{display: "none"}}
                  onChange={(e) => handleSelectVideo(e)}
                />
                {!isUploading && (
                  <div className="row mt-2">
                    <button
                      className="mx-auto mr-3"
                      onClick={clearVideo}
                      style={{borderRadius : '8px',color : 'white' , background:'red ' , paddingLeft: '5px' , paddingRight:'5px'}}
                    >Delete</button>
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
)
```

Note : This works in my local machine, but when it goes to test server I get this error of 413 Request Entity too large.

I've read and tried so many things from docs, even used 'body-parser' not default 'express.bodyParser', but did not work out.